# Debian Server timeout every 5/6 minutes for ~20 seconds

Tags: debian, timeout

I've a machine running Debian for a long time (maybe 7 years) 24/7. Two weeks ago I decided to move the location of the server, and upgrade to Debian Jessie (was running wheezy).

Everything went great, except that for every 5 or 6 minutes the server don't respond to any connection for around 20 seconds.

I've create a script to check when that happen, here is the times:

```
2017-01-12 16:16:05 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 16:21:49 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 16:27:32 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 16:33:13 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 16:39:01 TIMEOUT!
...
2017-01-12 17:07:59 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 17:13:47 TIMEOUT!
2017-01-12 17:19:25 TIMEOUT!
```

I have a virtual machine running on the server, and the packet reach it fine, without any delay. I've tested different ports on the server, like 80, 443, 9000, etc and all timeout. On the server for example running ssh, if I try a command during the timeout, for example typing 3 times "ls", after it recover it will receive the 3 "ls" and execute.

I've checked the logs on the server, but couldn't find any information related to it.

EDIT: Leaving ping running doesn't show timeout.

EDIT2: Ok, another strange thing. Accessing ssh on the server, and running ping 8.8.8.8 (or probably any command that output text) when the timeout start happening, I can still view the text output of the ping without any problem, if I do CTRL+C to cancel it, I see the min/avg/max status of the ping, but if I type a command (for example "ls") it waits until the server is available again to display the list of files.

EDIT3: So, It may be something disk related. The sda is a Samsung SSD 840 Pro 120GB.

iostats show the following:

**Normal behaviour**:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    20.00    20.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    20.00    20.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00    20.00    20.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

**Timeout behaviour**:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00  136.00     0.00 69124.00  1016.53   127.69 1053.93    0.00 1053.93   7.35 100.00
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00    16.00    0.00   18.50     0.00   540.00    58.38     0.10    5.51    0.00    5.51   1.19   2.20
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00   521.34 363490.00    0.00 363490.00 1000.00 100.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00   521.35 363492.00    0.00 363492.00 1000.00 100.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: This sounds like a connectivity issue. Try to leave a ping running and see if it you receive timeouts. Are you able to request a KVM on the server to really see what's going on on the server-side?

Comment: @Alex, forgot to add that information. Ping doesn't show timeout. Didn't understand the last part.

Comment: Do you have direct(phisycal) access to your server?

Comment: @Alex yes I have

Comment: If you ping 8.8.8.8 from your server, do you get any timeouts?

Comment: Ok, another strange thing. Accessing ssh on the server, and running ping 8.8.8.8 (or probably any command that output text) when the timeout start happening, I can still view the text without any problem, if I do CTRL+C to cancel it, i see the min/avg/max status of the ping, but if I type a command (for example LS) it waitings until the server is available again.

Comment: Check the disk's performance with `iostat -dkx 2`. Last column should say the percentage of disk usage.

Comment: Updated the main post with that information. I think that might be the issue, still don't know the reason or the solution.

Comment: Ok, seems the problem is redis, that is probably writing a lot of stuff from memory to disk, just checked with iotop.

Comment: Ok, I've disabled redis persistence on disk, because I don't need it! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using **iostat** and **iotop** for diagnosis I found that the issue was in redis-server that was persistence the database into disk, and because of the database growth, for some reason the written in disk block network traffic and that was the reason for the timeout (massing write into disk).

Because I don't need persistence in disk, I've disabled it and now works great again, but I don't know why redis-server behave this way.